# I keep getting this error when trying to install anything on mac big sure

Tags: homebrew, macos-big-sur

> `` $ brew install `mongodb-community@4.4 ``

It returns:

> `` Error: Failure while executing; `tar --extract --no-same-owner --file /Users/frankline/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/302d48e748531e0994cd7b3caf9bc7069ec6c132b710dc1bb8e33b725495056e--icu4c-69.1.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz --directory /private/tmp/d20210613-34193-g4tpe7` exited with 1. ``

Here's the output:

> `tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '/Users/frankline/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/302d48e748531e0994cd7b3caf9bc7069ec6c132b710dc1bb8e33b725495056e--icu4c-69.1.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz're`

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. I'm having almost the exact same error on my Mojave 10.14.6. Every time I try to install anything or run `brew upgrade`, it goes fine until brew says `==> Pouring openjdk--16.0.2.mojave.bottle.tar.gz`, or something equivalent in any other package, and after that brew outputs around 100 lines of errors that say something like `openjdk/16.0.2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/classlist: Write failed`, capped off by the error described in the question.

Comment: Update: I just rebooted and my problem went away. I hope yours did too.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem when I executed `brew upgrade`. It returns:

> ==>installing dependencies for python@3.9: **gdbm, mpdecimal, openssl@1.1** and **xz**.
> ==>Installing python@3.9 dependency: **gdbm**
> ==> Pouring gdbm-1.19.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
> tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/37cae0aa5a09881f7ab73dab85cc31f096f5dd68aa99e80a4ccac9957292d63d--gdbm-1.19.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz'
> Error: Failure while executing; `tar --extract --no-same-owner --file /Users/xxx/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/37cae0aa5a09881f7ab73dab85cc31f096f5dd68aa99e80a4ccac9957292d63d--gdbm-1.19.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz --directory /private/tmp/d20210615-1870-15pgco1` exited with 1. Here's the output:
> tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '/Users/lichong/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/37cae0aa5a09881f7ab73dab85cc31f096f5dd68aa99e80a4ccac9957292d63d--gdbm-1.19.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz'

Here is my solution: first install the dependency, i.e., `brew install gdbm` and then upgrade. Hope this can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

brew install "dependency" and brew upgrade worked for me!
The specific dependency in my case was pcre2, not `--gdbm` as above.